# Grails, need to read a textfile using the url in order to get a ssl-certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl, grails, certificate

To order a certificat, tomcat-8.5.9, the publisher sent us a textfile an told us to make it accessable from our url e.g. https://my.site.com/theTextFile.txt

How can I do that? Do I need to include it in my GrailsProject or can I put directly on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it means what it says on the tin, and all depends on your setup:

`https://my.site.com/theTextFile.txt` =

does your site run SSL ? if so what is in front of port 80 ? apache or equivalent webserver  then yes as you say you could add the text file to your virtual folder of your app and serve it but obviously that may be serving your port 8080 traffic so you could introduce a rewrite rule in apache to take care of it or you could put the text file in your grails application:

As an example in my url mapping I have a line like this:

`"/googleXXXXXXX.html" (view: '/googleVerification')`

The contents of the view is simply

`google-site-verification: googlea6XXXXX`

So do the same

`"/theTextFile.txt" (view: '/textFile')`

In the root of your `grails-app/views/textFile` contains:

`SOMETEXT`

Comment: Yes, my site runs SSL but with my own made certificate and it works well so you just need to enter the url as: "https://example.com" and you are in. But I just run TOMCAT without anything else in front. Do I need that?

Comment: so if example.com hits tomcat aka your grails application as the root meaing when you visit `http://example.com/` if that = your grails application the follow the UrlMapping example and add the rule and gsp page to your app

Comment: Thank's a lot vahid! Thats what I needed. I also have spring.security so I also had to make modifications in application.groovy but then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this answer to help anyone that have the same problem as I had.

In short,
My application "example.com" is setup for using TOMCAT-8.5.9 listening to port 443 using a certificat from a publisher. When asking the publisher for that certificate I'm told to put a file "AJK3GFU5I99GANY467G.txt" on the root of my application so that he can read this file from url: "https://example.com/AJK3GFU5I99GANY467G.txt".

In my grails project I copied this file into the filemap "myproject/grails-app/views/" and renamed the file to "certVerification.gsp".

Now I edit the UrlMappings.groovy file and added the line

```
"/AJK3GFU5I99GANY467G.txt"(view: "/certVerification")
```

And that should be all if it wasn't for I installed the spring.security-plugin. 
I have to edit the file: "application.groovy" and add a couple of lines:

```
[pattern: '/AJK3GFU5I99GANY467G.txt', access: ['permitAll']],
[pattern: '/certVerification', access: ['permitAll']],
```

And then you can access the file through: 
"https://example.com/AJK3GFU5I99GANY467G.txt"

Now I'm ready to ask the publisher for my certicate and later install it on tomcat. 
Hope everything will be ok this time...